# How to optimize mongo query with two parallel array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a query like this:

```
xml_db.find(
    {
        'high_performer': {
            '$nin': [some_value]
        },
        'low_performer': {
            '$nin': [some_value]
        },
        'expiration_date': {
            '$gte': datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        },
        'source': 'some_value'        
    }
)
```

I have tried to create an index with those fields but getting error:

> pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: cannot index parallel arrays [low_performer] [high_performer]

So, how to efficiently run this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compound indexing ordering should follow the `equality --> sort --> range` rule. A good description of this can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48759005/1092767) response.

This means that the first field in the index would be `source`, followed by the range filters (`expiration_date`, `low_performer` and `high_performer`).

As you noticed, one of the "performer" fields cannot be included in the index since only a single array can be indexed. You should use your knowledge of the data set to determine which filter (`low_performer` or `high_performer`) would be more selective and choose that filter to be included in the index.

Assuming that `high_performer` is more selective, the only remaining step would be to determine the ordering between `expiration_date` and `high_performer`. Again, you should use your knowledge of the data set to make this determination based on selectivity.

Assuming `expiration_date` is more selective, the index to create would then be:

```
{ "source" : 1, "expiration_date" : 1, "high_performer" : 1 }
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, it clarifies a lot of confusion of mine regarding effective indexing.