# MongoDB does not use compound index for sorting stage

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection and I have specified a compound index. The index is used for filtering however the sorting is done in memory and I can not figure out why.

I have the following documents:

```
{ _id :1, 
  accountId: 1234566,
  positionId: 9090,
  eventDateTime: "2021-01-02T09:38:45",
  nonce: 1415,
  event: {
    symbol: "value1"
  }
}
```

The index I am using is

```
db.data.createIndex({"accountId" : 1, "positionId" : 1, "event.symbol" : 1, eventDateTime: -1, "nonce": -1})
```

my query is

```
db.data.find({"accountId" : 123456, "positionId" : 9090, "event.symbol": { $in :["value1" , "value2", "value3"]}).sort({"eventDateTime" :-1, "nonce": -1})
```

and after using explain I get the following plan (abbreviated) :

```
"executionStats": { 
  "executionSuccess": "true",
   "nReturned" : 9
    "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
     "totalKeysExamined" : 10,
      "totalDocsExamined" : 9,
      "executionStages" : {
        "stage" : "SORT"
        "sortPattern" : {
          "eventDateTime" : -1,
           "nonce" : -1
          },
          "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR"           
             }
              "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH"           
                }

                 "inputStage" : {
                   "stage" : "IXSCAN" 
                    "keyPattern" : {
                      "accountId" : 1,
                       "positionId" : 1,
                        "event.symbol" : 1,
                        "eventDateTime" : -1,
                        "nonce" : -1
                     }          
                   }
}
```

The strange thing for me actually is that if using the index :

```
 db.data.createIndex({"accountId" : 1, "positionId" : 1, eventDateTime: -1, "nonce": -1})
```

in the same query the sort is not performed in memory.
I struggle to understand what is happening and the reason that the first index does not work. Any help would be much appreciated.

After I changed also the index to

```
db.data.createIndex({"accountId" : 1, "positionId" : 1,  eventDateTime: -1, "nonce": -1, "event.symbol" : 1,})
```

to match ESR suggestion the sort is also executed in memory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB - Index not being used when sorting and limiting on ranged query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739615/mongodb-index-not-being-used-when-sorting-and-limiting-on-ranged-query)

Comment: under the plan part of the explain, what does it show for "multiKeyPaths"?

Comment: See this post and it discusses using compound index with a filter+sort query: [Mongoid winningPlan does not use compound index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66748120/mongoid-winningplan-does-not-use-compound-index/66758651#66758651)